# How to give title in dropdown while using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

While using sql query for dropdown function, I need the title to be displayed as ALL Years and after clicking that title "ALL Years" the years to be displayed as "2003,2004,etc". And while selecting "All years" the details of all the consecutive years should be obtained.

Find below the query and suggest me a solution to solve this.

```
    select distinct years from years;
```

Comment: This question is super thin on details and can't really be answered because it's not clear what you're asking for. What's wrong with that query?

Comment: select distinct years from years;             I mean by this query, I am only able take individual year details.In drop down I want to add "All"  and when clicking on it, I want to display all year details.

Answer (score 0):

Add "All Years" from back-end side in drop-down, when user select "All years", use "-1" as years to retrieve data for all years using below Query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT years FROM years WHERE years = @years OR @years = -1;
```

Comment: Instead of doing this in the query, just run one of two different queries depending on the incoming parameter.